# Which of the following functions is not everywhere differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Today, I took a FAMAT test and had this question:

Which of the following is not everywhere differentiable?

$A) \sin\left(\frac 1{x^2 + 1}\right)$

$B) \ln(x^2)$

$C) \arctan(x)$

$D) \sqrt{1 + \cos^2(x)}$

$E)$ none of the above

I thought it was $B$, but the test reported the correct answer as $A$. Could someone please explain?

Comment: As explanation, I would go for "the answer is wrong." The function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is $C^\infty$ by composition.

Comment: You are correct; the test report isn't.